# If a song was released in 2014 as a single, and released the following year (2015) on an album, what's the true release date of the song?

Tags: music-business, release, playlists

I'm creating a playlist and want to include certain songs released as singles in a previous year, but were also released on an album the following or vice-versa.

*Examples*:

**Kendrick Lamar**

Released "i" in 2014 as a single, which later featured on Pimp a Butterfly in 2015.

**Adele**

Released "Send My Love (To Your New Lover)" in 2016 as a single, the song was previously included on her 2015 album, 25.

**Lady Gaga**

Released "Paparazzi" in 2009 from her 2008 album, The Fame.

Would it be reasonable to lump the 2014 single into a Best of 2015 playlist?

Comment: If you really want to sort by date, the important date would be when it peaked on the charts - which might be neither of those dates.  Some singles don't chart until they're featured in a movie or TV show.

Answer (score 3):

My opinion is a song's true release date is the date it was published, not the date of it being played live on album or introduced as a single live. The true date is the date when it appears on CD or DVD or SACD, whatever.

Answer (score 2):

If a song is released as a single, that is its release date. Subsequent inclusion on an album does not change that date.

For example, Blur released She's So High as a single in 1990; it was then included on their Leisure album, released in 1991. The release date of She's So High remains 1990.

(source: [Discogs](https://www.discogs.com/artist/7551-Blur))